# "at the beginning" vs. "at the start"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

I use the expression "at the beginning" a lot. And Google Ngram gives this plot

[image]

So, is "at the beginning" more idiomatic than "at the start"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions are idiomatic English. Neither word should raise an objection.